# XSLT 2.0 reformatting dates

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Say I have a date that I composed in the form "2018-03-00". I want this to be "00-MAR-18". What functions, in XSLT 2.0, if any, are available for this.

I was looking for month(3) = MAR. And I was going to compose the additional fields myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`format-date()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-format-date).

With the day being "00" your date isn't castable as an xs:date. If you really have "00", you won't be able to use `format-date()`.

If your dates are castable as xs:date's, here's an example...

**XML Input**

```
<test>2018-03-01</test>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-date(., '[D01]-[MN,*-3]-[Y01]')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<test>01-MAR-18</test>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtj

**EDIT**

Since your dates aren't really dates, you could create your own function...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:so="stackoverflow.test">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:function name="so:format_month">
    <xsl:param name="date_string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="months" select="(
      'JAN','FEB','MAR',
      'APR','MAY','JUN',
      'JUL','AUG','SEP',
      'OCT','NOV','DEC')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="date_tokens" select="tokenize($date_string,'-')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="($date_tokens[3],
      $months[number($date_tokens[2])],
      substring($date_tokens[1],3,2))" separator="-"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="so:format_month(.)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtj/2

Comment: Yes. MAR. Thanks.

Comment: Since I have a zero day - the format-date will fail.

Comment: @paulj - I added another option.

Comment: I was hoping not to build my own calendar lookup, but it is what it is. Thanks